# Laravel 5.2, Load a view based on user information

Tags: php, laravel-5

This is a fresh installation of Laravel 5.2, the only thing I did was to add a new column to the table users this new column is call roles which is just integers...
What I'm trying to do is to load a controller/view base on the information of this column...
Say if the column roles has a value of 1 then load the view X
in my routes file I have this

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    Route::auth();
if(Auth::user()->roles == '1') {
    Route::get('/admin', 'AdminController@index');
    Route::post('/admin', 'AdminController@save');
    Route::get('/admin/{datas}', 'AdminController@datas');
    Route::get('/admin/list', 'AdminController@list');
    Route::get('/admin/list/{details}', 'AdminController@details');
} else {
    Route::get('/login', 'UsersController@login');
}
```

if I use this `Auth::user()->roles == '1'` inside a view it "works" but is not what I want and I really don't want to install 3rd packages for user control, I just want something very simple... so how can I accomplish this?...

Comment: Just grab the column data in your controller function (send all posted data to this one controller function for that page), do the processing in the controller based off your option selected, and then return a view based on the option selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what Matt said(I didn't get it at first, I'm new to laravel so bear with me), this is what I did...

Install a fresh laravel...
then run this `php artisan make:auth`, it will install everything you need for users to register/login/reset...
then open your AuthController.php change this `protected $redirectTo = '/home'` for whatever you want, in my case I called delegate `$redirectTo = '/delegate'`
then on your routers.php file put something like this

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    Route::auth();
    Route::get('/delegate', 'DelegateController@index');
});
```

You don't actually need a view for this route, what you need is the controller... 
On this controller DelegateController.php will put something like this

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests;
use Auth;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;


// use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class AdminController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }
    //
    public function index() {
        // TODO Gets Data...
        $datos = ['Nombre', 'Otro Nombre', 'Otro mas'];

        // Return Data to tyhe view...
        if(Auth::user()->roles == '11') {
            return View('admin.home', compact('datos'));
        } else {
            return View('/welcome');
        }
    }
}
```

And thats how you get different views based on users information... at least is working for me..

**------------Update**

After I play a little bit with this, I find out that that even when you load the correct view for admin / user / customer / providers...etc the url/path is not correct here is why:
with the code above you get
 foo.com/login when user loads the Delegation Controller which serves the correct view but the url stays as foo.com/delegate if the user is an admin we want something like foo.com/admin not /delegate and even if you change it manually from /delegate to /admin it still work, but here is the problem because if the user is not an admin it will still shows the admin panel and we don't want that... to fix that I had to change my delegation controller... instead of loading a view I have to redirect the user to a correct path...

```
public function index() {
    if(Auth::user()->roles == '10') {
         return redirect()->route('admin');
        } else {
         return redirect()->route('/');
        }
    }
```

this isthe same code as before but instead of loading a view I redirect the user, in order for this to work properly in your routes file you have to declare each  the name of each path as follow

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    Route::auth();
    Route::get('delegate', 'DelegateController@index');
    // Add your route
    // Route::get('admin', 'AdminController@home');
    Route::get('admin', ['as'=>'admin', 'uses'=>'AdminController@home']);
});
```

That way you can redirect your user to any part of your site by calling the names route `return redirect()->route('/myprofile')` ...etc
Now that this is working we need to do one last check as to what user is loading what, to do that is very simple on each of your view controllers you should have something like this...

```
class AdminController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
        // gets the disco bouncer working...
        if(Auth::user()->roles != '10') {
            Auth::logout();
        }

    }
    //
    public function home() {
        // TODO Gets Data...
        $datos = ['Nombre', 'Otro Nombre', 'Otro mas'];
        // TODO build a model for the actual data...
        // Return Data to the view...
        return View('admin.home', compact('datos'));

    }
}
```

As you can see we can use this on all Controllers and skip the DelegationController but then you going to have to do a menu for each user role on a single app.blade master view which will look a lot more dirty...
If you ask me, yes I'm having fun learning Laravel!